# How to fix spacing with multi-line cgloss4e examples?

Tags: linguistics, gb4e, cgloss4e, pinyin

(**Note:** This is a follow-up to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/433624/how-to-combine-cgloss4e-colouring-and-pinyin))

I am using `cgloss4e` to write down some language examples. Some of these examples do not fit within a single line, therefore I am trying to distribute their content on multiple lines which, however, belong to the same *numbered example*.

**Problem.** When i distribute the content onto multiple lines, the spacing among the paragraphs seems to change in an unexpected way.

**Example.**

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[AutoFallBack=true]{xeCJK}[2018/02/27]
\setCJKmainfont[FallBack=NotoSansCJKtc-Regular]{NotoSerifCJKtc-Regular}
    % NOTE: download NotoSerifCJKtc-Regular font from here
    %       https://www.google.com/get/noto/help/cjk/
\usepackage{xpinyin}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\let\eachwordtwo=\pinyin
\newcommand{\glit}[1]{\nobreak\glt {\it ``{#1}''}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\glosscolor[1]{\gdef\@glcolor{#1}}
\glosscolor{red}
\AtBeginDocument{\colorlet{savedcol}{.}}
\def\@glosscolor{savedcol}

\newcommand{\clt}{\gdef\@glosscolor{\@glcolor}\color{\@glosscolor}}
\newcommand{\clf}{\gdef\@glosscolor{savedcol}\color{\@glosscolor}}

\gdef\getwords(#1,#2)#3 #4\\% #1=linebox, #2=\each, #3=1st word, #4=remainder
   {\setbox#1=\vbox{\hbox{#2{\strut\color{\@glosscolor}#3} }% adds space
                    \unvbox#1%
                   }%
    \def\more{#4}%
    \ifx\more\empty\let\more=\donewords
    \else\let\more=\getwords
    \fi
    \more(#1,#2)#4\\%
   }
\gdef\donewords(#1,#2)\\{\gdef\@glosscolor{savedcol}}   
\makeatother


\begin{document}

Normal spacing:

\begin{exe}
\ex
  \glll
    你  \clt 為甚麼      \clf 學    中文       ？ \\ 
    ni3 \clt wei4shen2me \clf xue2  Zhong1wen2 ?  \\ 
    You \clt why \clf study Chinese ?  \\
  \glit
    {Why do you study Chinese?}
\ex
  \glll
    \clt 因為     \clf 我  在   中國       工作 \\
    \clt Yin1wei4 \clf wo3 zai4 Zhong1guo2 gong1zuo4 \\
    \clt Because  \clf I   in   China      working \\
\glit
    {Because I am working in China}
\end{exe}

Incorrect spacing:

\begin{exe}
\ex
  \glll
    你  \clt 為甚麼      \clf 學    中文       ？ \\ 
    ni3 \clt wei4shen2me \clf xue2  Zhong1wen2 ?  \\ 
    You \clt why         \clf study Chinese ?  \\
  \glit
    {Why do you study Chinese?}
  \glll
    \clt 因為     \clf 我  在   中國       工作 \\
    \clt Yin1wei4 \clf wo3 zai4 Zhong1guo2 gong1zuo4 \\
    \clt Because  \clf I   in   China      working \\
\glit
    {Because I am working in China}
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

**Output.**

[image]

Normally, the line enclosed by the `glit` command is placed immediately below the three-lines example.

However, when I remove `ex` because I want multiple three-lines with the same number, the spacing changes. In the picture above, it can be clearly seen that the sentence *''Because I am working in China''* is placed further away from its corresponding text.

Ideally, I would like to be able to make multiple `glll` groups belong to the same `ex` numbered example without these spacing issues.

**Question.** Why is this happening, and how can I fix this?

Comment: I’ve written an answer below. **Note**: `SimSun` is a trademark of ZHONGYI Electronic Co., Beijing, which is licensed to Microsoft exclusively. Please remove the download website information in your MWE.

Comment: @RuixiZhang thank you very much for letting me know. I'll fix the code ASAP.

Comment: I added a cleaner solution. Also, I provided additional information on Open Source Fonts Collection for Chinese at the end. :)

Comment: @RuixiZhang can't thank you enough for warning me about fonts usage, and also for the nice answer. I fixed the code/example in this question and I will do the same for previous questions of mine shortly after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unwanted vertical spacing is caused by the `flushleft` environment. See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27697/164314) for a description.

## New answer

Since we are patching a lot of commands, I’d recommend using the [`etoolbox`](https://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package. This approach makes your preamble code cleaner and easier to follow. And, you don’t need to copy the full original definition from `cgloss4e.sty` to make your adjustments.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
% Not needed for this problem
%\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\usepackage[AutoFallBack=true]{xeCJK}[2018/02/27]
%\setCJKmainfont[FallBack=SimSun-ExtB]{SimSun}
    % Removed!
    % Removed!
    % Removed!
\usepackage{xpinyin}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\let\eachwordtwo=\pinyin
%\newcommand{\glit}[1]{\nobreak\glt {\it ``{#1}''}}
% I changed your original definition of \glit:
\newcommand{\glit}[1]{\glt ``\emph{#1}''\par}

\usepackage{etoolbox}% https://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter% Group everything to save the trouble
% My patches:
\patchcmd{\gll}% The command to be patched
  {\begin{flushleft}}% Code to be replaced
  {\begingroup\raggedright}% New code
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\glll}% The command to be patched
  {\begin{flushleft}}% Code to be replaced
  {\begingroup\raggedright}% New code
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\gl@stop}% The command to be patched
  {\end{flushleft}}% Code to be replaced
  {\endgroup}% New code
  {}{}
% Your color customization:
\newcommand*\glosscolor[1]{\gdef\@glcolor{#1}}
\glosscolor{red}
\AtBeginDocument{\colorlet{savedcol}{.}}
\def\@glosscolor{savedcol}
\newcommand{\clt}{\gdef\@glosscolor{\@glcolor}\color{\@glosscolor}}
\newcommand{\clf}{\gdef\@glosscolor{savedcol}\color{\@glosscolor}}
% Your patch written in the style of \patchcmd:
\patchcmd{\getwords}% The command to be patched
  {\strut#3}% Code to be replaced
  {\strut\color{\@glosscolor}#3}% New code
  {}{}
\gdef\donewords(#1,#2)\\{\gdef\@glosscolor{savedcol}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

Normal spacing:

\begin{exe}
\ex
  \glll
    a   \clt aaa         \clf a     aa         ? \\
    ni3 \clt wei4shen2me \clf xue2  Zhong1wen2 ? \\
    You \clt why         \clf study Chinese    ? \\
  \glit
    {Why do you study Chinese?}
\ex
  \glll
    \clt aa       \clf a   a    aa         aa        \\
    \clt Yin1wei4 \clf wo3 zai4 Zhong1guo2 gong1zuo4 \\
    \clt Because  \clf I   in   China      working   \\
  \glit
    {Because I am working in China}
\end{exe}

Incorrect spacing (now corrected):

\begin{exe}
\ex
  \glll
    a   \clt aaa         \clf a     aa         ? \\
    ni3 \clt wei4shen2me \clf xue2  Zhong1wen2 ? \\
    You \clt why         \clf study Chinese    ? \\
  \glit
    {Why do you study Chinese?}
  \glll
    \clt aa       \clf a   a    aa         aa        \\
    \clt Yin1wei4 \clf wo3 zai4 Zhong1guo2 gong1zuo4 \\
    \clt Because  \clf I   in   China      working   \\
  \glit
    {Because I am working in China}
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

## Original answer

To get around this issue, I used a patch:

```
\makeatletter
\def\gll%                 % Introduces 2-line text-and-gloss.
   {\begingroup\raggedright
     \ifx\@gsingle1%           conditionally force single spacing (hpk/MC)
        \vskip\baselineskip\def\baselinestretch{1}%
        \@selfnt\vskip-\baselineskip\fi%
    \bgroup
    \twosent
   }
\def\glll%                 % Introduces 3-line text-and-gloss.
   {\begingroup\raggedright
     \ifx\@gsingle1%        conditionally force single spacing (hpk/MC)
        \vskip\baselineskip\def\baselinestretch{1}%
        \@selfnt\vskip-\baselineskip\fi%
    \bgroup
    \threesent
   }
\def\gl@stop{{\hskip -\glossglue}\unhbox\gline\endgroup}
\makeatother
```

To get proper paragraph break, I also changed your definition of `\glit`:

```
\newcommand{\glit}[1]{\nobreak\glt {\it ``{#1}''}\par}
```

A full MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
% Not needed for your problem
%\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\usepackage[AutoFallBack=true]{xeCJK}[2018/02/27]
%\setCJKmainfont[FallBack=SimSun-ExtB]{SimSun}
    % Removed!
    % Removed!
    % Removed!
\usepackage{xpinyin}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\let\eachwordtwo=\pinyin
%\newcommand{\glit}[1]{\nobreak\glt {\it ``{#1}''}}
% I changed your original definition
\newcommand{\glit}[1]{\nobreak\glt {\it ``{#1}''}\par}

\makeatletter
% My patches:
\def\gll%                 % Introduces 2-line text-and-gloss.
   {\begingroup\raggedright
     \ifx\@gsingle1%           conditionally force single spacing (hpk/MC)
        \vskip\baselineskip\def\baselinestretch{1}%
        \@selfnt\vskip-\baselineskip\fi%
    \bgroup
    \twosent
   }
\def\glll%                 % Introduces 3-line text-and-gloss.
   {\begingroup\raggedright
     \ifx\@gsingle1%        conditionally force single spacing (hpk/MC)
        \vskip\baselineskip\def\baselinestretch{1}%
        \@selfnt\vskip-\baselineskip\fi%
    \bgroup
    \threesent
   }
\def\gl@stop{{\hskip -\glossglue}\unhbox\gline\endgroup}
% Your patches:
\newcommand*\glosscolor[1]{\gdef\@glcolor{#1}}
\glosscolor{red}
\AtBeginDocument{\colorlet{savedcol}{.}}
\def\@glosscolor{savedcol}
\newcommand{\clt}{\gdef\@glosscolor{\@glcolor}\color{\@glosscolor}}
\newcommand{\clf}{\gdef\@glosscolor{savedcol}\color{\@glosscolor}}
\gdef\getwords(#1,#2)#3 #4\\% #1=linebox, #2=\each, #3=1st word, #4=remainder
   {\setbox#1=\vbox{\hbox{#2{\strut\color{\@glosscolor}#3} }% adds space
                    \unvbox#1%
                   }%
    \def\more{#4}%
    \ifx\more\empty\let\more=\donewords
    \else\let\more=\getwords
    \fi
    \more(#1,#2)#4\\%
   }
\gdef\donewords(#1,#2)\\{\gdef\@glosscolor{savedcol}}   
\makeatother


\begin{document}

Normal spacing:

\begin{exe}
\ex
  \glll
    a  \clt aaa      \clf a    aa       ? \\ 
    ni3 \clt wei4shen2me \clf xue2  Zhong1wen2 ?  \\ 
    You \clt why \clf study Chinese ?  \\
  \glit
    {Why do you study Chinese?}
\ex
  \glll
    \clt aa     \clf a  a   aa       aa \\
    \clt Yin1wei4 \clf wo3 zai4 Zhong1guo2 gong1zuo4 \\
    \clt Because  \clf I   in   China      working \\
\glit
    {Because I am working in China}
\end{exe}

Incorrect spacing:

\begin{exe}
\ex
  \glll
    a  \clt aaa      \clf a    aa       ? \\ 
    ni3 \clt wei4shen2me \clf xue2  Zhong1wen2 ?  \\ 
    You \clt why         \clf study Chinese ?  \\
  \glit
    {Why do you study Chinese?}
  \glll
    \clt aa     \clf a  a   aa       aa \\
    \clt Yin1wei4 \clf wo3 zai4 Zhong1guo2 gong1zuo4 \\
    \clt Because  \clf I   in   China      working \\
\glit
    {Because I am working in China}
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

[image: Spacing correct]

### Side note

`SimSun` is a trademark of ZHONGYI Electronic Co., Beijing, which is licensed to Microsoft exclusively. Any use of `SimSun` outside the Windows operating system may be considered as trademark infringement. If you want a “serif” looking CJK font, please consider using the [Source Han Serif](https://source.typekit.com/source-han-serif/) font released in 2017, which is free and open sourced. You can also download Source Han Serif from the [Google Noto Fonts](https://www.google.com/get/noto/help/cjk/) website.

If you want to use other open sourced CJK fonts, take a look at [Open Source Fonts Collection for Chinese](https://fatetypo.xyz/osfcc/?variant=zh-hk) (website in HK Traditional Chinese, judging from the stroke of your `甚` character).